# How can I get a file from CamScanner or Office Lens in a web app running on Android?

Tags: android, html, angularjs, google-chrome, file-upload

I have an Angular web app that I access via Chrome on Android. I can use:

`<input type='file' accept='image/*' capture>`

(or a similar `accept` attribute with ng-file-upload) to upload images to the server directly from the camera app. Very cool. But I'd like the user to be able to choose, say, `CamScanner` or Office Lens instead of the camera app so they can format documents prior to uploading.

I've played around with the `accept` attribute but can't seem to get those apps to show up on Android's "Complete action using" app list.

Ideas?

Comment: i think the only way to do this is under android application using JavaScript Interface, only there you can do whatever you want...

Comment: there is a Cordova Plugin called CameraPreview https://github.com/mbppower/CordovaCameraPreview this allows you the get the camera preview into your app without opening the actual cameraapp. in the Readme you can see that you can do pretty much everything with the image generated

Answer (score 5):

At this point, there's no way to do that, unless you are working on a standalone APP.

The browser behavior for an element `<input type="file"/>` relies only on the default APP for handling Photos and Videos.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at this?

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Relevant example from the link:

Here's an intent that launches the Zxing barcode scanner app. It follows the syntax thus:

```
intent:
   //scan/
   #Intent; 
   package=com.google.zxing.client.android; 
   scheme=zxing; 
end;
```

To launch the Zxing barcode scanner app, you encode your href on the anchor as follows:

```
 <a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>
```

So for camscanner, the package is

com.intsig.camscanner

So use that instead of com.google.zxing.client.android in the above example.

Comment: This looks like a step in the right direction, but I don't see a way to get the application's output (the scanned image) to upload to the server. Am I missing something?